# Converting standard looking characters to strange/crazy looking UTF-8 characters?

Tags: utf-8

The inspiration for this question comes from this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/11125

I want to write a script to convert standard looking characters (e.g. letters in the English alphabet), to UTF-8 characters that are unusual and makes me appear crazy.

Did `kiamlaluno` sift through the thousands of UTF-8 characters to find similar looking characters to English letters, or is there possibly a more automated way to do this?

I would like the answer in Python, but any programming language will probably give me a suitable solution.

For example, convert:

> PONY

to

> P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡

A decent excerpt from the SO answer:

.

co*̶͑̾̾​̅ͫ͏̙̤g͇̫͛͆̾ͫ̑͆l͖͉̗̩̳̟̍ͫͥͨe̠̅sZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ ISͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱ TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ?

Comment: The name of that technique is, in fact, "Zalgo". Look it up. It's using combining characters, so you don't have to *replace* anything, just stack lots of combining characters on each base character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a python module called [pyzalgo](https://github.com/mjgiarlo/pyzalgo/blob/master/zalgo.py).

```
>>> import zalgo
>>> print zalgo.zalgo('hello')
Ḩ̝̳͓̪̲͌̌͗̔́͌̄͢͢͢͢͢͢E̶̢̯̭̟̥̖̯̙̬ͪ̄̉ͭ͗̏́̈́L̢̢͓̺͇̠̠͉͙̪͍̽ͣͩ͂̾͒̊ͦL̵̶̶̢̬͈̬̦̜̥̲̜͓͎̝̣̙̞̝Ơ̷̸̴̷̘͙͕͈̞̜̠͙̰̬̰̣̟̭
```

It appears to be pretty straightforward and customisable after a quick look at the code.

Thanks for the info @hobbs.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps not "crazy looking", but something in the same vein:

https://github.com/reinderien/mimic